# Unittest fails in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, flask, python-unittest

I've recently a problem with unittest. I have a project for couple years. The overall structure of the project is this:

```
/project
  /app
  /app2
  /tests
  /utils
    /services.py
```

Until recently tests ran ok. But then, I guess, either Python plug-in or VS Code have been updated and problem has occurred.
The `app1` uses `utils.services` and runs just fine. When I run `python3 -m unittest tests` or `python3 -m unittest discover -s tests` in terminal tests run fine too.

But in VS Code I see no tests in the list and in Python output I see the error:

```
2023-11-20 17:25:33.469 [info] Discover tests for workspace name: order - uri: /Users/ralfeus/Projects/order/tests/__init__.py
2023-11-20 17:25:33.469 [info] Running discovery for unittest using the new test adapter.
2023-11-20 17:25:33.470 [info] Discovering unittest tests with arguments: /Users/ralfeus/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/discovery.py,--udiscovery,-v,-s,tests,-p,*test*.py

2023-11-20 17:25:33.470 [info] > ./bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/discovery.py --udiscovery -v -s tests -p *test*.py
2023-11-20 17:25:33.471 [info] cwd: .
2023-11-20 17:25:33.738 [info] Test server connected to a client.
2023-11-20 17:25:33.739 [error] Unittest test discovery error 
 Failed to import test module: addresses.test_address_api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 407, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/ralfeus/Projects/order/tests/addresses/test_address_api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.users.models.role import Role
  File "/Users/ralfeus/Projects/order/app/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from utils.services import get_celery, init_celery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.services'; 'utils' is not a package
```

I tried to play with unittest parameters in VS Code, tried adding or removing paths to `sys.path` based on different recommendations but all without effect. So now I'm out of ideas.
What else can be done?

Update: I've realized that if I change `from utils.services ...` to `from .utils.services` in `app/__init__.py` I'm getting an error:

> No module named 'app.utils'

That makes me think that when test discover runs in VSCode the root of the application is `/app` instead of `/`. But I have no indication of that and found no reason for such a behavior.

Comment: what command is VS Code running? How are you triggering it?

Comment: I assume it's `./bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/discovery.py --udiscovery -v -s tests -p *test*.py`

It's triggered by VSCode when I refresh list of tests

Comment: Can you confirm that? Do you get the same results when you run that yourself?

Comment: No, when I run this in terminal I'm getting something totally different:
`
./bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/discovery.py --udiscovery -v -s tests -p "*test*.py"
Error[vscode-unittest]: TEST_PORT is not set.  TEST_UUID =  None
Error: no uuid provided or parsed.
Error sending response: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Request data: Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/json
Request-uuid:

{"command_type": "discovery", "eot": true}
`
I suppose it has to run from within VSCode

Comment: Been at the same point couple of years ago. Problem seems to be that the test runner executes the tests at the level at which they were defined so therefore they have no access to modules in a higher folder structure. I accepted that I have to run pytest from the console. If you for some reason have to run in from VsCode I wish you the best of luck

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314758/vscode-python-unittest-discovery-fails-utils-is-not-a-package-sys-path-ord